# Windows 7 PC refusing to accept RDP connection

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, networking, remote-desktop

We operate a mainly Mac network but our 3 main video rendering machines are all Windows 7 PCs.

2 out of the 3 are accepting RDP connections but one of them just refuses to work both internally or externally.

All 3 have have Remote Desktop setup securely following this guide http://jack-brennan.com/securing-remote-desktop-on-windows-8-and-windows-7/

The RD ports are random and are definitely open and set up identically in terms of the port forwarding etc. After turning on firewall logging on the router for the problem PCs ACL, I can see the connection coming in and it being passing onto the correct static IP.

Currently the Windows firewall is completely disabled on the PC itself.

I have logon events enabled on the PC but don't seem to be seeing the attempts being logged.

As our users need to connect to these PCs from home (generally on Mac OS X) I am currently testing the the connection using MS Remote Desktop app on OS X. As I said the other 2 PCs work perfectly but I am now at a loss at to why this particular one will not work.

When I try to connect (externally) I get "Initializing" & "Negotiating Credentials" messages and then nothing, the app eventually times out and stops trying to connect.

Can anyone think of anything that I might be missing or can try to test what the issue might be on this one PC?

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks, Justin

Comment: Is there any anti-virus installed on this specific PC?

Comment: AVG, exactly as with the other two PCs

Comment: Check if your AVG is active and blocking the connection.Are you able to ping?

Comment: its the free version so Firewall is not available but even after disabling AVG it still will not accept connections. Can ping successfully yes.

Comment: Open command prompt and type this command
netstat -an |find “3389″

The result should be like below:
TCP "ip adress ":3389 "ip adress " LISTENING                               If not LISTENING then there could be issue with security software which is blocking connection between 2 machines.

Comment: Telnet is your safe betm as @vembutech metnioned. Replace 3389 with your "random" port. Also, make sure that your port is not under 1024 (this might create some conflicts with other services). Next, something like Wireshark or Message Analyzer on either the client or the server (or both) will give you more information.

Comment: thanks for the advise guys... I tried the suggestion of @vembutech and the random port does return LISTENING although the IP address in the result is 0.0.0.0 - not sure if that's significant at all but I did check the adjacent PC (RDP connections are fine on it) and it returned the same result so I'm assuming the IP being "blank" is fine